# Product as input arguments?

Tags: scheme, racket

In lisp/scheme, is there any form using *set product* as function input? *map* form uses *n* length-equal lists for a function which needs *n* arguments. Sometimes, we need the arguments to come from the product of a group of sets. For example:

```
(pmap (λ (d p) foo)
           A B)
```

Here, list **A** may have different length with **B**, and **pmap** feeds each element of the product of **A** and **B** to the **lambda** expression.

Form *for** of scheme/racket can do this job:

```
(for* ([x '(0 2 4)]
       [y '(1 3 5)])
      ((λ (d p)
           (printf "(~a, ~a)\n" d p))
       x y))
```

Output:

```
(0, 1)
(0, 3)
(0, 5)
(2, 1)
(2, 3)
(2, 5)
(4, 1)
(4, 3)
(4, 5)
```

I want to know whether there exists other means similar to **map** or **fold** to do this in scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following implementation of `pmap`. It works using only `cons`, `car`, `cdr`, `null?`, `apply`, `map` and `reverse` and supports any number of arguments like `map` does.

```
(define (pmap f . xs) 
  (define (carry a xs ys then)
    (if (and (not (null? ys)) (null? (car ys)))
        '()
        (if (null? xs) 
            (then (reverse a))
            (if (null? (car xs))
                (if (null? (cdr xs)) 
                    '()
                    (carry (cons (car ys) a) (cons (cdr (car (cdr xs))) (cdr (cdr xs))) (cdr ys) then))
                (carry (cons (car xs) a) (cdr xs) (cdr ys) then)))))

  (define (pmap-helper f xs ys)
    (carry '() xs ys 
           (lambda (xs)
             (cons (apply f (map car xs)) 
                   (pmap-helper f (cons (cdr (car xs)) (cdr xs)) ys)))))

  (pmap-helper f xs xs))

(display (pmap list '(0 2 4) '(1 3 5))) (newline)
;((0 1) (2 1) (4 1) (0 3) (2 3) (4 3) (0 5) (2 5) (4 5))
```

The only difference is that the earlier lists are iterated over faster than later ones where as your example is the reverse. This `pmap` can be modified to do that:

```
(define (pmap f . xs) 
  (define (carry a xs ys then)
    (if (and (not (null? ys)) (null? (car ys)))
        '()
        (if (null? xs) 
            (then (reverse a))
            (if (null? (car xs))
                (if (null? (cdr xs)) 
                    '()
                    (carry (cons (car ys) a) (cons (cdr (car (cdr xs))) (cdr (cdr xs))) (cdr ys) then))
                (carry (cons (car xs) a) (cdr xs) (cdr ys) then)))))

  (define (pmap-helper f xs ys)
    (carry '() xs ys 
           (lambda (xs)
             (cons (apply f (reverse (map car xs))) 
                   (pmap-helper f (cons (cdr (car xs)) (cdr xs)) ys)))))

  (let ((xs (reverse xs)))
    (pmap-helper f xs xs)))

(display (pmap list '(0 2 4) '(1 3 5))) (newline)
; ((0 1) (0 3) (0 5) (2 1) (2 3) (2 5) (4 1) (4 3) (4 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know such a thing is not present in the standard. It is however not a problem to write one.

For an overview over useful list functions, I can recommend srfi1, which gives you quite a few useful operations besides map and fold.

http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html